# How to avoid asynchronous in service angular - socket io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I tried using debugger to see whats been goin in my factory-angular, i found out whats been causing the error in my **socket variable** the whole time is the asynchronous behavior of the JS, is there a way to initialize first my **socket variable** via http-get before loading the functions('on' and 'emit') inside my factory?...

```
 'use strict';

    app.factory('getgameip', ['$http', '$location', function($http,$rootScope, $location) {
        return {
            getGameip: getGameip
        };
        function getGameip() {
              debugger
                return $http.get('/getip/test');
        }

    }]);

    app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope,$http,$location,getgameip) {
      debugger
       getgameip.getGameip().then(function(data) {//1st step
        debugger
        //3rd step
        //this socket variable would be used in the 'on function' and 'emit function' below
          var socket = io.connect('http://'+data.data[0].ip+':'+data.data[0].port);
         });

      return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
        //2nd step
          debugger
           socket.on(eventName, function () {  //i got error on socket io because it has not been initialized yet
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
          });
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              if (callback) {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
              }
            });
          });

        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: Side note: You should really use the breakpoints in developer tools rather than those many `debugger` statements 0.o

Comment: I can't even find the documentation for that `connect` method... that's the beauty of socket io docs!

Comment: @T J - debugger is a type of breakpoint for scripts...and here's the doc for  '.connect' method.. http://socket.io/docs/ really, its in the first page

Comment: I know what debugger keyword does, I was saying instead of polluting code with all those debugger statements, you should use developer tools to set break points. And, there is no documentation for connect method, it's just used in some example. I can create a connection like `io('http://localhost/')` without the connect method as well, nobody says what exactly it does or what's the difference. I wouldn't call it documentation of that method.

Comment: Im trying to connect to a remote server, in w/c case io('http://localhost/') isn't applicable

Comment: I was giving an example that there's no need to use `connect` method, and there's no documentation for why a `connect` method exist.